# How to arrange rows in custom order from column in R

Tags: r

I am trying to group all row that has the same index and create a new column to identify them.

This is what the sample looks like:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   vehicle_id                  location           time     for_hire_light
   <chr>                       <chr>              <chr>             <dbl>
 1 Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk 100.65867,13.82991 17:28:20              1
 2 Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk 100.65927,13.82969 17:29:29              0
 3 Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk 100.65927,13.82969 17:32:20              0
 4 Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk 100.50572,13.82972 17:35:37              0
 5 Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk 100.65931,13.89867 17:37:37              0
 6 Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk 100.50979,13.82972 17:38:37              1
 7 B07m6lXRMBM+lINefeDSBJf+uZM 100.50979,13.82972 22:40:37              1
 8 B07m6lXRMBM+lINefeDSBJf+uZM 100.48224,13.78539 22:41:30              0
 9 B07m6lXRMBM+lINefeDSBJf+uZM 100.66742,13.90093 22:42:30              0
10 B07m6lXRMBM+lINefeDSBJf+uZM 100.66916,13.90055 22:44:30              1
```

```
my.df <- structure(list(vehicle_id = c("Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk",
"Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk", "Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk",
"Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk", "Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk",
"Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk", "Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk",
"B07m6lXRMBM+lINefeDSBJf+uZM", "B07m6lXRMBM+lINefeDSBJf+uZM",
"B07m6lXRMBM+lINefeDSBJf+uZM"), location = c("100.65867,13.82991",
"100.65927,13.82969", "100.65927,13.82969", "100.50572,13.82972",
"100.65931,13.89867", "100.50979,13.82972", "100.50979,13.82972",
"100.48224,13.78539", "100.66742,13.90093", "100.66916,13.90055"), 
time = c("17:28:20", "17:29:29", "17:32:20", "17:35:37", "17:37:37",
"17:38:37", "22:40:37", "22:41:30", "22:42:30", "22:44:30"),
for_hire_light = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)), 
row.names = c(NA,-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Thus, I want to create new trips separate from the "for_hire_light" column.
I am looking to find those rows where `for_hire_light` switches from `1` to `0` and get info from all the following rows until `for_hire_light` switches back to `1`.

These are what the results' example that I prefer:

```
| Trip ID | location          | time   | from_vehicle_id           | 
| ------- | ----------------- |------- |-------------------------- |
| 1       | 100.65927,13.82969|17:29:29|Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk|
| 1       | 100.65927,13.82969|17:32:20|Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk|
| 1       | 100.50572,13.82972|17:35:37|Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk|
| 1       | 100.65931,13.89867|17:37:37|Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk|
| 2       | 100.48224,13.78539|22:41:30|B07m6lXRMBM+lINefeDSBJf+uZM|
| 2       | 100.66742,13.90093|22:42:30|B07m6lXRMBM+lINefeDSBJf+uZM|
```

something like this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `data.table::rleid()` function for this.  I have used it two times to safely get the results and eliminate possibility when same trip_ids over vehicles may get merged together.

```
library(data.table)
my.df %>% group_by(vehicle_id) %>% mutate(trip_id = paste(vehicle_id, rleid(for_hire_light))) %>%
  ungroup() %>% filter(for_hire_light == 0) %>%
  mutate(trip_id = rleid(trip_id))

# A tibble: 6 x 5
  vehicle_id                  location           time     for_hire_light trip_id
  <chr>                       <chr>              <chr>             <dbl>   <int>
1 Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk 100.65927,13.82969 17:29:29              0       1
2 Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk 100.65927,13.82969 17:32:20              0       1
3 Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk 100.50572,13.82972 17:35:37              0       1
4 Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk 100.65931,13.89867 17:37:37              0       1
5 B07m6lXRMBM+lINefeDSBJf+uZM 100.48224,13.78539 22:41:30              0       2
6 B07m6lXRMBM+lINefeDSBJf+uZM 100.66742,13.90093 22:42:30              0       2
```

---

similarly this one should get you same results

```
my.df %>% mutate(trip_id = rleid(vehicle_id, for_hire_light)) %>%
  filter(for_hire_light == 0) %>%
  mutate(trip_id = dense_rank(trip_id))

# A tibble: 6 x 5
  vehicle_id                  location           time     for_hire_light trip_id
  <chr>                       <chr>              <chr>             <dbl>   <int>
1 Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk 100.65927,13.82969 17:29:29              0       1
2 Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk 100.65927,13.82969 17:32:20              0       1
3 Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk 100.50572,13.82972 17:35:37              0       1
4 Zxyz/iqsgUz7IYalVCi+saUo5Dk 100.65931,13.89867 17:37:37              0       1
5 B07m6lXRMBM+lINefeDSBJf+uZM 100.48224,13.78539 22:41:30              0       2
6 B07m6lXRMBM+lINefeDSBJf+uZM 100.66742,13.90093 22:42:30              0       2
```